# Trouble understanding intent.getaction();

Tags: android, bluetooth

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    // When discovery finds a device
    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
        mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    }
 }
};
// Register the BroadcastReceiver
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
   registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy`
```

This above code is used to scan for BluetoothDevices and add them into the mArrayAdapter.
However I do not understand these lines `String action = intent.getAction();`

`if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))`

Can someone please provide a brief explanation. I have already searched but I simple don't understand the use of a intent.getaction() . What does it return and how is the value set?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's actually quite simple.

Every intent is just a message. But, you can send intents from one app to another. So, when you receive an intent from another app(bluetooth controller in this case), you need to know what it means. That's basically what action is for.

And, because broadcast receiver can usually receive several different types of intents, that 'if' makes sure that the intent you just received really means that Bluetooth device has been found.

I recommend you read this fine article about intents and intent filters: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Edit: As pomber suggested, in your case, it really isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the `if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))` is not necessary, because you are only registering that broadcast receiver with the filter `new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)`.